# How can I use a bool value in class in a method which has changed in another method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
 public class CustomizationUI : MonoBehaviour
 {
private bool ifTGOn = false;
private bool ifTBOn = false;

......(some variable declaration)
int tg=0;
int bg=0;
int tb=0;
int bb=0;
string gender = "boy";
   public async void loadTopMaterialCards()
{
    if (gender == "boy"){
        if (tb==0){
    contentPanelTB.SetActive(true);
    contentPanelBB.SetActive(false);
    ifTBOn = true;
    Debug.Log("I ammmmmmmmmmmm ifTBON"+ifTBOn);
    for (int i=0; i<topBoyMaterials.Count; i++){
        
    AsyncOperationHandle<GameObject> handle = Addressables.InstantiateAsync("MaterialCard");
    await handle.Task;

    GameObject matcard = handle.Result;
    matcard.transform.SetParent(ViewPanelTB);
    MaterialCard mcard = matcard.GetComponent<MaterialCard>();
    mcard.image.sprite = topBoyImages[i];
    mcard.material = topBoyImages[i].name;
    }
    tb++;
    }else if (tb==1){
        contentPanelTB.SetActive(true);
        contentPanelBB.SetActive(false);
        ifTBOn = true;
    }
    }
    
    Debug.Log("I am TG and TB at the second time"+ifTGOn+ifTBOn);
}
public async void loadBottomMaterialCards()
{
    Debug.Log("I am TG and TB at the third time"+ifTGOn+ifTBOn);
    if (gender == "boy"){
        if (bb==0){
    contentPanelTB.SetActive(false);
    contentPanelBB.SetActive(true);
    ifTBOn = false;
    for (int i=0; i<bottomBoyMaterials.Count; i++){
        
    AsyncOperationHandle<GameObject> handle = Addressables.InstantiateAsync("MaterialCard");
    await handle.Task;

    GameObject matcard = handle.Result;
    matcard.transform.SetParent(ViewPanelBB);
    MaterialCard mcard = matcard.GetComponent<MaterialCard>();
    mcard.image.sprite = bottomBoyImages[i];
    mcard.material = bottomBoyImages[i].name;
    }
    bb++;
    }else if (bb==1){
        contentPanelTB.SetActive(false);
        contentPanelBB.SetActive(true);
        ifTBOn = false;
    }
    }
    Debug.Log("I am TG and TB at the fourth time"+ifTGOn+ifTBOn);
}
public void changeMaterial(){
    Debug.Log("HIIII iam panellll"+ifTBOn);
}
void Awake(){
    instance = this;
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
   
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}
```

}
In the method loadTopMaterialCard() I set the bool ifTBOn to true after press a button(in unity), the debug inside loadTopMaterialCard did show that it has been set to be true, however, I try to debug in changeMaterial() after ifTBOn has been set to true, but it show false.
This is the whole piece of the class, I don't know why the bool is always false when debug it  in the class changeMaterial()
How can I fix it?

(I dont think there is someplace in my code to edit the bool back to false

Comment: Can you show us more complete code where you are actually trying to access those bools from a different method?

Comment: hi I have edited the post to show more completely, could u pls help me with this?

Comment: my guess is that '......' hides a lot more code. Is this is visual studio? You can set a watch and ask the debugger to break when the value of that bool changes

Comment: I guess you are charging the state of ifTBOn some where else in the code. It doesn't make sense

Comment: You mentioned clicking buttons. Are you working with the same INSTANCE of `CustomizationUI` in both locations? If you are creating an instance of the class with `new` in both places that would explain the symptom. If this is the case, you'd need to move the declaration of the class out so that it is accessible to both locations and you're using the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is likely that your booleans aren't being set to true in the first place. There should be no problem accessing it in multiple methods.

I'd step through this code with breakpoints and ensure that your if statements are passing and the code is reaching the point where it can set the boolean to true.

If it is, then there must be somewhere else in the code that you're setting them back to false.

Outside of those two things, we'd need to see the second method you're accessing them in and any other code that touches the fields.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried to set it be true at first but it seems doesnt work, I have edited my post to show a more complete code.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I was saying it likely wasn't getting set to true. Looking at your code now though I imagine LoadBottomCards is getting hit and reverting it to false. Put breakpoints in to make sure you're following whenever it gets set, that'll tell you why it's false.

Comment: Also, I strongly encourage you to use better variable names. It's almost impossible for someone to understand what any of this means because the variable names tell you nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I am picky, but I strongly recommend not to use such variable names. In my opinion are misleading, meaningless and quite ugly. I hope you can find better names in the future.

A part of that, you have *loadBottomMaterialCards* method, in which you set **ifTBOn** to *false*.

I presume this method is execute without your knowledge.
Try to set a breakpoint there and see if the *instruction pointer* goes there.

Good luck and remember the names <3